# How to create the select and radio HTML tag dynamically?

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I am creating a form and in the form, all the input fields will display dynamically. I am able to create the text, email, password, checkbox but not able to create the select and radio. I have to use the select tag for country and radio for gender.

I am using CodeIgniter.

[image]

```
<?php
$example_from_name = array('name' => 'user_from_view'); //assigning form name
echo form_open('formbuilder_control/example_from_view',$example_from_name);
foreach ($data as $key) {
    $exp_fields_name=$key->fields_name; //here I am getting the name of field name                
    $exp_fields_type=$key->fields_type; //here I am getting the input type 
    ?>
    <div class="form-group row label-capitals">
        <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label"><?php echo $exp_fields_name;?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <input type="<?php echo $exp_fields_type;?>" name="<?php echo $exp_fields_name;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $exp_fields_name;?>" class="form-control" />
            <?php echo form_error($exp_fields_name); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
}
?>
<div class="form-buttons-w btn_strip">
    <input type="submit"  value="Save" class="btn btn-primary margin-10">
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: You can't directly give this like text box. Add it based on `field_type` using if condition

Comment: @KMS, Can you explain little bit more, I used like this because I want text, select, radio, checkbox etc.

Comment: Actually, If I used the if and else then, I am not getting the all the output. I need all the fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough dynamic data for some of the fields.  You will have to pass more from your database.  A few of the fields will require values (select, radio, checkbox)  Here is the basic structure (as the others were trying to say):

```
<?php
$example_from_name = array('name' => 'user_from_view'); //assigning form name
echo form_open('formbuilder_control/example_from_view',$example_from_name);
foreach ($data as $key) {
    $exp_fields_name=$key->fields_name; //here I am getting the name of field name                
    $exp_fields_type=$key->fields_type; //here I am getting the input type 
    echo "<div class=\"form-group row label-capitals\">";
        echo "<label class=\"col-sm-5 col-form-label\">$exp_fields_name</label>";
        echo "<div class=\"col-sm-7\">";
            if(in_array($exp_fields_type,['text','email','password'])){
                echo "<input type=\"$exp_fields_type\" name=\"$exp_fields_name\" class=\"form-control\" />";
            }elseif($exp_fields_type=='checkbox'){
                echo "<input type=\"$exp_fields_type\" name=\"$exp_fields_name\" value=\"[something needed here]\" class=\"form-control\" /> $exp_fields_name";
            }elseif($exp_fields_type=='select'){
                echo "<select name=\"$exp_fields_name\">";
                    echo "<option></option>"; // you will have to determine a way to populate the options
                    // ... more options
                echo "</select>";
            }elseif($exp_fields_type=='radio'){
                echo "$exp_fields_name <input type=\"$exp_fields_type\"  name=\"$exp_fields_name\" value=\"[something needed here]\" class=\"form-control\" />";
            }else{
                echo "Whoops, uncaught field type!";
            }
            echo form_error($exp_fields_name);
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
echo "<div class=\"form-buttons-w btn_strip\">";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Save\" class=\"btn btn-primary margin-10\">";
echo "</div>";
echo form_close();
```

We, volunteers, cannot help you with the missing components of your design.  You will need to figure out how you are going to pass the necessary options/values to the necessary html form elements.

---

If you have known field names, you might try writing the conditionals using `$exp_fields_name` instead of `$exp_fields_type` to cover a few exceptional cases.  Perhaps exchange the above if-block with the following:

```
if($exp_fields_name=='gender'){
    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"gender\" value=\"male\" class=\"form-control\" /> Male<br>";
    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"gender\" value=\"female\" class=\"form-control\" /> Female";
}elseif($exp_fields_name=='country'){
    echo "<select name=\"country\" class=\"form-control\" />";
         echo "<option>India</option>";
         echo "<option>Sri Lanka</option>";
         echo "<option>Japan</option>";
         //  ...continue as needed
    echo "</select>";
}else{  // all other types default to input tag
    echo "<input type=\"$exp_fields_type\" name=\"$exp_fields_name\" class=\"form-control\" />";
}
```

I assume "checkbox" inputs will have multiple inputs, so you may need to write a custom check for that group as well.

Comment: I want to know In case I have 2 select tags than I have to use one more esleif condition for select tag?

Comment: Thanks for the help, your code is working for me.Upvote from my side.

Comment: Can you help me in below link?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730730/else-part-is-working-while-autosave-the-data-using-codeigniter

Comment: I am so sorry, There is no internet connection at my home.I am replying from my mobile.I am from INDIA and the time is now 10.45pm.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use IF or switch using this type:

```
<?php
    if($exp_fields_type == 'text'){
        $input = '<input type="text" name="'.$exp_fields_name;.'" value="" placeholder="" />'; 
    }else if($exp_fields_type == 'radio'){
        $input = '<input type="radio" name="'.$exp_fields_name;.'" value="" placeholder="" />';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I need all the fields. I mean text, radio, select, checkbox

Comment: And your radio code will display only single radio. I have to display male and female.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will works only for input tags. So you should check the type before creating the tag
for example :

```
<?php
  if($exp_fields_type == 'select'){        
    $input = '<select name="'.$exp_fields_name.'"  placeholder="" >
                <option value="">option 1 </option>
              </select>'; 
  }else if($exp_fields_type == 'textarea'){
    $input = '<textarea name="'.$exp_fields_name.'"></textarea>';

  }else {
    $input = '<input type="'.$exp_fields_type.'" name="'.$exp_fields_name.'" value="" placeholder="" />';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Geeth. I  have to display all the fields.

Comment: i made some changes in the code. please take a look. and you need check the type for all tags other than 'input'

Comment: I tried your code but I am not getting output.even I am not getting any input field.You have missed the semicolun(;) in the second elseif  and there is an extra semicolon in the else conditon in name="'.$exp_fields_name;.'"

Comment: its just a sample code to create the tags. display it with echo eg. echo $input; if this is not working, try to check which condition is executing, and check the value of $exp_fields_type for each type

Comment: I don't want to use if-else if-else condition here because I want to display all the text type, select type, radio, checkbox every think.If I use your code then it will display the only true condition