# Else part is working while Autosave the data using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have more than 30 fields and I am trying to save the data in the database automatically.

I am able to insert the data in the database but it's continuously inserting. It's not updating the last record.  It's not checking the else part.

I am getting the total count of the `stud_id` and updating the record with the help of `stud_id`. Is it a good idea?

```
public function student_autosave($data){
    $sql_count_id="SELECT COUNT(stud_id) FROM student_info";
    $q = $this->db->query($sql_count_id);
    $last_count=$q->num_rows();
    if ($last_count == 1) {
        $this->db->insert('student_info',$data);
    }else{
        $query = $this->db->where(['stud_id'=>$last_count])->update('student_info',$data);
        if($this->db->affected_rows()>0){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        } 
    }
}
```

**Autosave script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    timePicker(10);
});

var s;
function timePicker(vr) {
    if (vr > 0) {
         if (vr > 1) {
             $('#timer').html('Data will be updated in next '+ vr+' secounds');
         } else {
             $('#timer').html('Data will be updated in next 1 secound');
         }
         vr--;
         s = setTimeout('timePicker(' + vr + ')', 1000);
     } else {
         clearInterval(s);
         $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url: '<?php echo base_url("index.php/Student_controller/student_data_autosave"); ?>',
             data: $('form[name="student_formname"]').serialize(),
             success: function (data) {
                 s = setTimeout('timePicker(' + 10 + ')', 5000);
                 return false;
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My new answer to this is: Redesign your process.

- Short of generating a unique form id for new users on every new page load, you won't be able to confidently differentiate between users.  Furthermore if something happens to a user mid-form and the form id is "lost", then the user will have to start all over because the next time they load a form, it will have a new random generated id. (well, the deeper truth is, you could probably find a way preserve a form id when things go wrong, but it is an unnecessary convolution)
- Using a timer to auto-save is an unnecessary feature and will certainly lead to wasteful/undesirable calls to the server/database.  Imagine someone starts filling the form, goes to the toilet, has a coffee, takes a phone call to a relative, has to pick up the kids from school, remembers that a few things are needed from the grocery store... you get the idea.  In the meantime, your page is auto-saving over and over.  There is absolutely no benefit to putting this zombie on the treadmill.

When I immigrated to Australia, I had to fill government forms online.  The forms were long.  They did the sensible thing; they broke the form up into chunks of 5-7 questions/fields and offered Back/Next buttons.  Every time I clicked one of those buttons, my progress was saved.  It was not a horribly clunky experience and the truth is, I did need to step away or make a phone call to retrieve some personal information for the form.  These forms, once I submitted so much as an email address, were assigned a permalink (which was emailed to me asap) so that even if I became disconnected, I could pick right up where I left off.

Using this story, my recommendation is this:

- Page 1 of your form must be the bare minimum contact information, so that your program can assign an id (auto-incremented primary key) to each new user.
- Because I recommend that you email a permalink to the user, you can double your benefit by using it to verify that the user has actually used an email that is real and that they can access.  This means that they will enter their name & email (& password), the form will pause while the user receives your automated email, they click the permalink that automatically places them on the page that they need to continue on, and you get confirmation that the registration is (probably) legitimate.
- Every time your user clicks Back/Next, you update the database.  You can do this with ajax or you can submit the page the simple/old-school way with pure html/php.
- No matter how slow the user is, or if they suffer a crash/disconnection, your program will not perform any mindless-calls and you can even build in some very necessary validations and checkpoints.

Lastly, always sanitize and validate everything that a user submits before using the data in a query -- likely always and forever.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I got an error in  if($result->num_rows() && $last_count=$result->row->count){   and error is Message:  Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_result::$row

Comment: @NarendraVerma Yes, sorry for my typo.  I've updated the answer.  But the truth is I think there is a design/logic problem with your code (as I have stated in my answer).

Comment: This time is working but also got an issue. student_id is 1 submitted in the database now I have to submit the student_id 2 but my code is updating the student_id 1

Comment: @NarendraVerma Yes, I speak about that in my answer.  I suppose you can use `if($last_count==0){` to query `INSERT` `}else{` `UPDATE`.

Comment: But It's every time updating my last records after submitting. I mean I am not able to insert the student_id 2. because of if condition if($last_count==0){ // this is working first time if there will be no records in the database. After adding the id 1 only update part is working .

Comment: I'm trying to tell you that your design logic seems flawed, but I cannot help you because I don't fully understand your table structure & data and design.  I don't know what your project is meant to do.  What I do feel confident about, is that I wouldn't be using the process that you are using.  Please read my post a few times and maybe you will have an epiphany.  Otherwise, we may need a full blown discussion about the intended process.  (I will not be available to chat properly for ~24 hrs at minimum)

Comment: I added table image in the question.

Comment: Your SELECT should have a WHERE clause which targets the specific user by `stud_id`.

Comment: WHERE clause Where should I use it? I will explain you again. My table is empty then I will get zero counts and using this  condition ( if($last_count==0){  ) insert function will work. Now the second time again ( COUNT(stud_id) AS count) query will work and this time I will get the count 1. Now the if condition will not satisfy then else part will work and every time else part is working. It's not inserting the new record

Comment: Unfortunately, your project needs a complete re-think.  1. Why is it necessary to autosave based on a time interval?  2. How will you confidently associate users to rows in the database?  3. Are your users logging in? 4. Might you only autosave if a few primary/required field are filled?  There are many ways that your current design can become unreliable.  I'm happy to discuss but this probably better done in a chatroom or email.  It is too late for me tonight, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: 1) Why is it necessary? Ans: Because I have more than 5 fields and in future, I will add more field.If there is some issue in the user browser or any technical issue then he can retrieve the data using this name and email.

Comment: 2)Ans: This is the registration form. No need to associate the user.3) Ans: I am not using logging here. 4)Ans: I need all the fields to be filled That I will manage it.

Comment: I have created a simple form. I need when user type anything in the field that data automatically saved in the database. Now your code is working same but it is updating the last record I mean I am not able to insert more than 1 row.

Comment: @NarendraVerma I have completely rewritten my answer to give you the very best advice I can for you project.

Comment: I agree with your answer. but I have more than 25 fields in the form.Can you share your email id? I will share the code.

Comment: As far as granting me private access to vital question information, I must refuse.  It would be unfair to other volunteers if I am exclusively privileged to new information.  Also, any advice that I would give would be disconnected to the question written on this page.  You may/should add your new code (jsfiddle) to the question as an edit.

Comment: Yes, I added jsfiddle link in above comment. Please check it. I only shared the JS, CSS and HTML code.

Comment: Your new jsfiddle demo looks like you are on the right path.  Changing this question now will throw out the two currently posted answers. I still question whether javascript submissions are necessary at all.  Unfortunately your question is becoming a bit too broad and volunteers are not meant to solve "projects" just individual problems.  What I recommend is, if you are going to take the advice in my answer, you may mark it as the accepted answer.  Then continue to develop your new approach, and post a new question when you encounter a specific/isolated issue.

Comment: If you would like me to clarify my answer, I can try to do that within its general scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157256/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-mickmackusa).

Answer (score 0):

Need small correction, like below

`num_rows()` - Gives the number of rows returned by the query, that is number of rows that the result has fetched when selecting, this is not count, you have to access count separately

```
$sql_count_id="SELECT COUNT(stud_id) as count FROM student_info";

// perform your query,
$q = $this->db->query($sql_count_id);

// if there were rows returned and
if($q->num_rows() ){

       // count ==1 then
       if($q->row()->count == 1){

             // perform your insert

       }else{

            // perform your update
        } 
}else{
     // something went wrong with your query
    // should return atleast 1 even if count is zero
}
```

Comment: I got an error in line if($q->row()->count == 1){ and errror is Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$count

Comment: what you have in `print_r($q->row());`

Comment: stdClass Object
(
    [COUNT(stud_id)] => 0
)

Comment: what's your sql ?, you may not be having `as count`, so got error

Comment: The Same query I am using it which is in the question

Comment: @NarendraVerma just use alias like `SELECT COUNT(stud_id) as count`

Comment: I want to ask something. My stud_id is primary key then it will start from 1 but In the print_r($q->row()); I am getting 0. If there is no records in the database

Comment: And one more issue is It's updating only last record continue. I have to insert the new record  but that is also updating the last records

Comment: Any more help in this?

Comment: I didn't get you what do you mean by last record continue

Comment: I have created a simple form. I need when user type anything in the field that data automatically saved in the database. Now your code is working same but it is updating the last record I mean I am not able to insert more than 1 row

Comment: probably the reason, everytime your update replaces previously updated data, is that so ?

Comment: Yes, It's updating my previous data because of IF condition.First user data inserted properly but not able to insert the second user data. It's updated only first user data. I think it always checking if condition (if($q->row()->count == 1)) and this if condition is not satisfying and process going to else part